# can't connect to github via ssh

Tags: git, github, ssh

I tried to clone one of my repositories on github from my newly installed linux machine running manjaro with fluxbox. i set up the user.name and user.email and uploaded the correct ssh key. but i always get

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I googled it and found that i should do `ssh-keygen -R github.com` which should delete github from my known_hosts file but the known_hosts file doesn't even exist yet, because i just finished setting up a new linux install.

so i tried `ssh -vT git@github` which gave me

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/masterkraft0r/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.128)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

which is way over my head. can somebody tell me what went wrong and maybe how to fix this mess?

Comment: Is your home directory on this server owned by your user, or by root?  What exactly was the name of the "correct" key file you copied to your user account, and precisely where did you put it?  Can you please add the output of `ls -la ~masterkraft0r/.ssh/` to your question?  Also, FYI, kräftor is crayfish in Swedish. :)

Comment: If you typed `yes` in response to the prompt, the ssh client would update your `known_hosts` file itself.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Did you try to add github as known host?

If you have an existing `known_hosts` file and do not want to overwrite (as @Puce suggested in the comment), use this.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

This will add the rsa key to the end of the known_hosts.

If you have no idea what `known_hosts` is/means, or you never engaged with it for sure, you can simply write a new one, but note that this will remove the existing one if you had any.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Also carefully follow the [instruction](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) again. Most of time people forget to do a step or two.

Comment: Np. I'd be appreciated if you check this one as answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: This removes all existing entries, if the known_hosts file already exists!

Comment: I think you'd be better off putting the edited version first considering the first version is destructive.

Comment: @toxaq will do. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Generate KEY

```
- cd   ~/.ssh

- ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@email.com"
```

NOTE -
Keys need to be only readable by you:

```sh
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If Keys need to be read-writable by you:

```sh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Step 2: Check the Contents and copy

```
cat ~/.ssh/nameOfFile.pub | pbcopy
```

Step 3: Configure your SSH key into Bitbucket (similar applies to Github)

GOTO settings => SSHKEY

```
- Add what you copied in Step 2 and give it a name
```

Step 4:  Clone your repository using SSH protocol

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:{username}/repo.git

git clone git@github.com:{username}/repo.git
```

This should work BUT

If you keep getting this error

```
[
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
]
```

Follow this steps.

```
i. ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org OR ssh -T git@github.com depending on which you are using { This will test your connection to Bitbucket OR Github).

ii. If you do not see a message similar  to (logged in as username.). Go to the next step

iii. ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity (identity is whatever name you saved the file when generating a key)

iv. You will get this message (Identity added: /path to ssh file/.ssh/mywork (youremail@email.com)
v. You can now clone your repository.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clone the repository, but you also use bitbucket or any other git tools, try to use `https` instead of `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also happens to me when  set the origin with newly generated ssh key  due to re-installation of windows.

When I Update the ssh key path (new generated) it solved my problem using the following code

```
 eval $(ssh-agent -s)
 ssh-add /d/key    **(path of new key d:/key)**
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm no expert on git, but looking at this it seems like something was wrong with the connection between the server and your PC. 
It says:

```
    Host key verification failed.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

That sounds like something went wrong when you received the data. Have you tried it multiple times and gotten the same response?

Try checking your internet connection, or if github was temporarily offline.