# Sublime Git pushing host key verification failed

Tags: windows, git, ssh, sublimetext3

So basically I pushed my project to gitlab by sublimegit.

Now I made a format to my windows7 and installed windows10, I placed the project folder in the same path as I used to have on old OS.

I have the privatekey from which I can generate `id_rsa` - I checked it and it also generates the same public key to gitlab.

I placed `id_rsa` to `Users/Me/.ssh` folder and to `Program files/Git/etc/ssh` and also created a folder in Git called `.ssh` and place it in there also.

```
Pushing to git@gitlab.placeholder.ee:HTML/stuff.git
Host key verification failed.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Can anyone see what kinda mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 12):

You should have `id_rsa` (private key) *and* `id_rsa.pub` (public key) both in `C:/Users/Me/.ssh`

Check that then environment variable HOME is defined (to `%USERPROFILE%`), which should be the case if you are calling `git-cmd.bat` or `git-bash.bat`, packaged in the [latest git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276665/6309) by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996481/help-me), and [seen in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32386975/6309), you also need to add the server key in the `C:/Users/Me/.ssh/known_host` file.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

### (this is what the [step 5 of `GitHub SSH / Generating SSH keys`](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-5-test-the-connection) does: that applies also for a gitlab server)

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Comment: added id_rsa.pub to C:/Users/Me/.ssh 
Pushing now gives a modified error :  key_load_public: invalid format

Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Comment: @Helpme What git version do you have?

Comment: git version 2.6.2.windows.1

Comment: @Helpme Make sure you have generated your keys with the right format: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10897752/6309 `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

Comment: I used puttygen to convert it to OpenSSH - SSH-2 RSA

Comment: @Helpme Try with a new set of keys generated directly with `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, if your conversion didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Basically I just needed known_hosts

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Right. I have included that step in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might install two (github.exe/ git.exe) clients,just try to move out the new one from PATH